# Can metabolism raising help us become thinner?

Tags: mental-health, weight, weight-loss, metabolism

I saw a article about the metabolism in Chinese.

It said that metabolism = 65% basal metabolic rate + 10% thermic effect of food + 25% daily activities, so I can write the math formula, X=65% X+10% X+25%, X as the metabolism above.

It also said that if you saw a guy who can't become fat even he usually ate a lot, it may be because his metabolism is high, and a guy who becomes fat even if he didn't usually ate much food, it maybe because that his metabolism is low.

So far, I think the metabolism can help us become fatter or thinner, because as we know, the higher basal metabolic rate, the faster we become thinner, and we have 65% basal metabolic rate in our metabolism. And if daily activities we did every day are almost the same, we can say it is a constant, that is, the element that causes us to become thinner or fatter is basal metabolic rate and thermic effect of food. If our metabolism becomes higher, I think we can consider our basal metabolic rate becomes higher too, because the percentage of basal metabolic rate is higher than the thermic effect of food. So,the basal Metabolic Rate and metabolism should be proportional to each other.

However, in some articles it said that basal if the metabolic rate raises, so does the metabolism raise. But basal metabolism raise, it doesn't mean that metabolism raise too. I am confused about this thinking. So metabolism raising can't let us become thinner. However, some articles say yes, metabolism raising "can" let us become thinner.

So I want to ask here: Can raising metabolism help us become thinner ?

Comment: Not really. The Basal Metabolic Rate is your constant. You can only change how much you eat and how much you work out.

Comment: i saw a product,(Herbal tea),it said that drinking this can increase the metabolism.So when i ate  almost the same food amount ,do almost the same activity.does it also increase the Basal Metabolic Rate  when i drink the Herbal tea to increase the metabolism?or does the Herbal tea to increase the thermic Effect of Food to increase the metabolism?so,in fact,we should said the Herbal tea just increase the thermic Effect of Food,not the metabolism

Comment: Yes, there was time when speed was prescribed for weight loss.

Answer (score 5):

[Basal metabolic rate](https://www.britannica.com/science/basal-metabolic-rate) is essentially energy expenditure at rest, whereas metabolism is a general term for net anabolism and catabolism - however, often metabolism is used to refer to basal metabolism + activity energy expenditure.

There are lots of [unsubstantiated product claims (i.e. scams)](https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ProtectYourself/HealthFraud/ucm326842.htm) for weight loss. I have not found evidence for herbal teas raising metabolic rate either reliably or safely.  There is no medication that can be prescribed *safely* to raise metabolism either, unless there is an underlying deficit in certain hormones that need to be corrected, which would be determined via testing if symptoms suggest that.

The best known way to raise resting metabolic rate is to increase lean body mass.  [This article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1038/oby.2011.262) discusses the association between low BMR and low muscle mass.